# Create GitHub PR Comment from Azure Pipeline

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pull-request

After a quick internet search I couldn't seem to find an easy way for my Azure Pipeline to write a custom comment back to the PR that triggered it. Is this possible? Does it require a PAT? I can't use any solution that requires exposing a PAT to a external PR, as they could then easily exfiltrate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can add comments to the PR on GitHub from Azure pipelines. You can use the **GitHub Comment** task in your pipeline to easily write comments to the GitHub PR.

[image]

With this task, you also need to create a [GitHub service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-github), or a [GitHub Enterprise Server service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-githubent) if your repository is hosted on GitHub Enterprise Server, for use on the task.

[image]

When creating the GitHub (or GitHub Enterprise Server) service connection, you can choose an authorization method from the optional.

- **GitHub service connection** -- **`Grant authorization`** or **`Personal Access Token`**

  [image]
- **GitHub Enterprise Server service connection** -- **`Personal Access Token`**, **`Username and Password`** or **`OAuth2`**

  [image]

So, a GitHub PAT is not required if the authorization method you choose is not **`Personal Access Token`**.

**[UPDATE]**

If you are worrying about that the service connection would be abused by someone to attack your source code repository, you can do the following things:

1. On GitHub, you can create a PAT, and limit the permission scopes of this PAT. More details, see "[**Creating a personal access token**](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token)".
2. On Azure DevOps, you can choose **`Personal Access Token`** as the authorization method on the service connection, and fill with the PAT that you created in above step. Then you can limit which users, teams and groups, even which pipelines, can use the service connection in the project. More details, you can see "[**Secure a service connection**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#secure-a-service-connection)".

Comment: So this task could safely be run on a PR from an external (untrusted) party on our microsoft/msquic repo?

Comment: Hi @NickBanks, The task is run in the Azure pipeline on Azure DevOps, not on the GitHub repository. Normally, this task is executing the related [Issue Comments API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/issues#comments) on the pipeline agent to add comments to the GitHub PR or issue. If you do not trust the Microsoft-hosted agent, you can install a self-hosted agent on you own machine to run the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks @Bright Ran-MSFT. My problem is that the external party can change any part of the code, including the pipeline yaml and then push a PR. It doesn't really matter which host runs things. If anything secret or special permissions to do things are given to that PR, then an attacker could abuse them. So I am just trying to understand if the process you outlines above does either of those.

Comment: Hi @NickBanks, I have updated my answer with more details, please check it. Any questions about this, feel free to tell us.